# How to use SynchronizingObject for event calls

Tags: c#, winforms

For an application that I'm working on I use [SpotifyLocalAPI](https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/SpotifyLocalAPI/#events), and I want to use the events that the API has. But, as someone who is into C# for a couple of months now, I'm not sure where to start. There is [another project based on this API](https://github.com/eltoncezar/Spofy/blob/master/Spofy/Classes/SpofyManager.cs#L91) that uses the events, but it's in WPF, and that makes it a different deal if I understand my googeling correctly. This means that for a WinForms I have to do things a bit differently, but I can't seem to figure out how.

The documentation of the API states that `You can set a SynchronizingObject, then the events will be called on the specific context`. When I look at how the WPF project did this, it has a function ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383884/setting-sync-object-in-wpf/3383913#3383913)) to do some magic, and *poof*, it works.

If I understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1841389/7193940) correctly the `SynchronizingObject` is a property of the `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface, which "[provides synchronous and asynchronous communication between objects about the occurrence of an event.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx#Remarks)".

Okay, so far so good. I think I understand the basic working of the interface, **but how am I supposed to work with it?** How do I convince the application that it should react to the event? How should I define the `_spotify.SynchronizingObject`? (Which is the main problem for me right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `SynchronizationObject` to be any UI element that implements `IShynchronizeInvoke` (`Form`, `UserControl` etc). Check out the example Winforms app [here](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/blob/281b684f5f80a14ed2b440ed4b0c514c1f630eec/SpotifyAPI.Example/LocalControl.cs#L25). Note that this is optional, and in that example app, they have chosen to use [`Invoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx) explicitly in the event handlers. The important thing to remember is that if you want to update the UI, then the code to do so must be run on the UI thread. Some more details on this [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml).

Comment: Thank you for all the information :) I totally overlooked the example winforms app that the API provided :c It works like a charm now! Back to more things to do and stuff to fix :p

Comment: @MagicLegend As the author of the library, I strongly suggest invoking on the UI-Thread inside the event-handlers. The problem: When setting the `SynchronizingObject`, the whole timer-callback (which also makes the web-request) will be called on the specific thread. In most of the cases, this is unwanted behavior. It will be removed once .net core support is finished.