# Saving an image from Helix Tookit

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

C#, WPF, [Helix Toolkit](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit). I am trying to save an image from a `HelixViewport3D` viewport (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814187/rendering-helixtoolkit-viewport-to-a-bitmap)) and am still having problems.

**Intended method:** Render image to viewport and simply save that using `Viewport3DHelper.SaveBitmap()` or similar method.

```
Viewport3DHelper.SaveBitmap(helixPlot.Viewport, @"E:\test.bmp", null, 4, BitmapExporter.OutputFormat.Png);
```

**The problem with that:** It runs but the captured image is blank. My best guess is that Helix Toolkit is rendering asynchronously(?) There is no image there to grab at the time that I am saving it.

**Possible workaround 1:** Respond to an event once rendering is complete.

**The problem with that:** There is no suitable event to subscribe to.

**Possible workaround 2:** Add an in-line delay to allow the image to render before saving it. (Clunky and unreliable, but would be a step in the right direction).

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Viewport3DHelper.SaveBitmap(helixPlot.Viewport, @"E:\test.bmp", null, 4, BitmapExporter.OutputFormat.Png);
```

**The problem with that:** The image doesn't get displayed until my code execution completes. If I add a delay of 10 seconds, I just get a blank screen for an additional 10 seconds.

**Possible workaround 3:** Add a timer so that the image will be rendered and I can then save the image from the timer elapsed event.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
...
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
timer.Interval = 2000; // two seconds
timer.Start();
....
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Viewport3DHelper.SaveBitmap(helixPlot.Viewport, @"E:\test.bmp", null, 4, BitmapExporter.OutputFormat.Png);
}
```

**The problem with that:** Although the image is rendered successfully and is there for the taking, the timer is running in a different thread to I cannot reference the HelixPlot control from the event handler. I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'
```

**Possible workaround 4:** Run the timer in the UI thread using `Timer.SynchronizingObject`

**The problem with that:** It doesn't seem to be possible to do this easily/simply in WPF. I can do it [with a lot of additional code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383884/setting-sync-object-in-wpf) and at the moment this may be my best available option, but it seems strongly sub-optimal for reasons of verbosity and lack of robustness.

Is there not some reasonably straightforward way of achieving what I am trying to do?

The root of the problem seems to be that the image is not rendered to the viewport until the calling method has finished executing. I don't really understand why this is.

EDIT: I have been told on another forum that Helix Toolkit is rendering on the WPF composite render thread. However, after some Googling I am still none the wiser as to how I can wait for this rendering to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer to this here:

[Asynchronous operations within a loop - how to keep control of execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63417050/asynchronous-operations-within-a-loop-how-to-keep-control-of-execution/63424918?noredirect=1#comment112164676_63424918)

There doesn't seem to be a completion event available, so the only way around it that I have been able to find is to use `async`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this saved me a lot of work!
I may add a little note: I had to add `Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render` at the `Dispatcher.Invoke` function to render the Billboards properly.